# dynamic binding DataGridComboBox Column

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dynamic, binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

i am currently developing a small wpf component, but since 2 days i am fighting with a strange problem inside the DataGrid. I try to reload the ItemSource of a DataGridComboBoxColumn. Its not possible to bind this column in the xaml to a ObservableList

My .xaml :

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Height="auto" Margin="0, 15, 0, 0"  x:Name="mapAttributesTable" ColumnWidth="Auto"
              SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding LinkedItems, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem ="{Binding Path=CurrentColumnObject, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="comboBox_TableFields" Header="TableFields" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Fields, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="ComboBoxColumn_SelectionChanged"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="JmsSubClass" Binding="{Binding Path= JmsSubClass}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="JmsFieldName" Binding="{Binding Path=JmsFieldName}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

My code behind:

```
    public IMap SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ILink>(SelectedItem.Links);
                OnPropertyChanged();
                this.Fields = new ObservableCollection<string>(SelectedDataMapItem.TableFields);
                OnPropertyChanged("Fields");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ILink> _items = new ObservableCollection<ILink>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Holds each created entry
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ILink> Items
    {
        get { return this._items; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this._items= value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private ILink _currentColumnObject;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public ILink CurrentColumnObject
    {
        get { return _currentColumnObject; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this._currentColumnObject = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> _fields = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Fields
    {
        get
        {
            return _fields;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this._fields = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

If any person (developer) has an idea, it will be nice to solve this problem.

best regards

Comment: If view model properties are settable, they should fire a property change notification in their setter. Your Items and Fields properties don't do that. It's also pointless to use ObservableCollection when you never add or remove items to/from the collection.

Comment: I cannot see you implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged but normally when you call it with no parameter that will cause a refresh of the whole viewmodel. This is occasionally required, but where possible you should only ever raise it on the specific property which has changed by passing the property name.

Comment: i thought for ObservableLists, its not necessary to do that.

Comment: That's a misunderstanding. You don't even need to use ObservableCollection here, because you never add or remove elements to/from the collection after it is created.

Comment: @user3797008 - that is true if you change the contents of the collection (add/remove items) they will raise a different INotifyCollectionChanged but this is not what you are doing. If you clear and then repopulate the observable collection that would be another way of solving your issue

Comment: It seems that my binding is not corretly working in the xaml, if i write   `this.comboBox_Fields.ItemsSource = (DataContext as DetailsDataMapViewModel).Fields; than the binding is working` the question is, why the xaml binding is not correct.

Comment: So the binding `{Binding Path=DataContext.Fields, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}` is not working? What UserControl are you trying to find? Does it not share the DataContext of the DataGrid? E.g. `{Binding Path=DataContext.Fields, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}`